# Slice dataframe by all rows corresponding to a country, then sample that vector

Tags: r, dataframe, logical-operators, subset

I have an R script that reads out some parameters via the commandArgs() function to see what kind of slices it should make in a dataset before saving these slices to a text file to be interpreted by a C++ program.
The dataset is a survey done in the EU and I would like to be able to slice per respondent's country, by having relevant arguments in the commandArgs vector be compared to a string vector `countries` that contains all possible options. Using that and a corresponding integer matrix `countryIndices`, which contains the bounds of each country (i.e.: all Belgian correspondents are in rows 1-1043, so `countryIndices[1,1]=1` and `countryIndices[2,1]=1043`), I wish to construct a matrix `personIndices`, that has all relevant bounds, using the which() function.

From this I want to make a vector that contains a sample of indices from the requested countries. The size of this vector is either `sampleSize*sampleCountries` (sampling sampleSize people per country) or simply `sampleSize`, depending on another parameter passed through. I was hoping that, at least for the latter type of sampling I could make this vector in one go, through the c() function, as follows

```
personIndices<-rbind(c(1,1043),c(2044,3061),c(8423,8922))
sampleVector<-c(personIndices[,1]:personIndices[,2])
```

And then sampling from that vector.

I'd hoped that this would make a vector containing the numbers 1:1043, 2044:3061 and 8423:8922, but this sadly does not seem to work. Any tips? Out of desperation I've constructed a monstrosity containing ifs in ifs in ifs and I'd rather not have it see the light of day if there's a smarter approach, but I haven't been able to find out. For reference as to what I'm doing (or if I wasn't being clear enough), said monstrosity can be found at http://pastebin.ca/2650188
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would add a new column to the dataset that indicates to which country the row belongs, then just operate on subsets of the data by this column instead of maintaining a countryIndices matrix

Comment: That's all unnecessary. Logical indexing/subsetting are all you need, using a new 'country' field (factor) you add to your data. See my answer. Like @6pool said.

Comment: +1 Downvoting is not cool, this is a bona-fide question, and is welcome. I had similar problems 'getting' R's idiom for logical indexing when I started. However, OP, in the light of the solutions, can you condense and change the question away from ***"I'm trying to do X with variable Y then index into Z"*** and to a broader ***"Here is what I want to do with this dataset"***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the acrobatics with vectors of indices are unnecessary.

Logical indexing, subsetting are really all you need, using a new 'country' field (factor) you add to your data. (Maybe also plyr::ddply if you get real fancy)

All you want to do is allow the user to:

1. Choose a country from a list (by selecting its number, 2-letter abbrev, whatever)...
2. ... then sample in your dataset from within that country. That's all!

.

```
dat$country <- NA  # insert a new column, initialize to NA for pessimism, to catch omissions
dat$country[1:1043,]    <- 'Belgium'
dat$country[2044:3061,] <- 'Bulgaria'
dat$country[8423,8922,] <- 'Czech Rep'
...
# Now make country a factor instead of character
dat$country <- as.factor(dat$country)

# Now you can sample() using either logical indexing...
sample(dat[dat$country=='Bulgaria',] , ...)
# ...or subsetting
sample(subset(dat,country=='Bulgaria'), ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would summarize your code as:

1. If `sampleType` is `TRUE`, then draw a sample of size `sampleSize` from the indices corresponding to each country in `sampleCountries`, and return all these sampled indices together.
2. If `sampleType` is `FALSE`, then group the indices corresponding to all the countries in `sampleCountries` together and draw a single sample of size `sampleSize`.

Let's setup some sample parameters:

```
sampleCountries <- c("BE", "WG")
sampleSize <- 20
sampleType <- F
```

The first step is to build a vector of the country for each index:

```
countries = c(rep("BE", 1043), rep("DM", 1000), rep("WG", 1018), rep("GR", 1003),
              rep("IT", 1021), rep("SP", 1021), rep("FR", 1008), rep("IR", 1000),
              rep("NI", 308), rep("LX", 500), rep("NL", 1022), rep("PT", 1000),
              rep("GB", 1066), rep("EG", 1014))
```

Next, when `"ALL"` is in `sampleCountries` you want to behave like all the countries are selected:

```
if ("ALL" %in% sampleCountries) {
  sampleCountries <- unique(countries)
}
```

Finally, draw your samples:

```
if (sampleType) {
  personIndices <- unlist(lapply(sampleCountries, function(x) {
    return(sample(which(countries == x), sampleSize, replace=F))
  }))
} else {
  personIndices <- sample(which(countries %in% sampleCountries), sampleSize,
                          replace=F)
}
```

In the first part of the if statement, `which(countries == x)` gets the indices of country `x`, and `lapply` does this for all the countries in your vector `sampleCountries`. Finally, `unlist` converts the output of `lapply` to a vector.

In the second part of the if statement, `which(countries %in% sampleCountries)` gets the indices of every country in `sampleCountries`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is a lot more elegant :)